# Is it important to leave mysql running in the background ? Is there a gui to control processes on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: mysql

Im using BootUp Manager (bum) to control auto-start processes on Ubuntu 12.04. I have stopped Apache2 from starting automatically using bum. The problem is, today I have found that sql server is always running in the back. I can not alter auto-start settings for MYSQL from bum.

Why I can not see any entry for MySQL in bum, moreover does sql needed by the Ubuntu OS itself for its own processes ? If not needed by the OS itself ,then is it safe to disable MySQL and restart it whenever I need it ? How should I do that ?

Is there any gui application for doing so ? Upto now Im using this command for start/stop apache2 and mysql

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start/stop/restart
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start/stop/restart or sudo start/stop mysql
service mysql status

Is it possible to create a .py file which add gui functionality to this.

Answer (score 2):

No, Ubuntu does not require mysql to be running. You have probably installed mysql while installing something else as well. To disable mysql from starting automatically you might want to execute:

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql disable
```

If you no longer want mysql installed at all then you can:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
```

Please note that if you remove the "mysql-server" package that your Ubuntu system probably will report that there are other packages that depend on it that may be removed. in that case, you will have to choose to do so or not, before proceeding.

Comment: Im seeing this error while using the first command you mentioned "update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/mysql missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/mysql do not exist."

Is there any other way to stop auto-start for MySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not needed for core Ubuntu functionality, so it's safe for you to start and stop it as you see fit. Your method of controlling the services is perfectly fine; you could also use the newer "service" system:

```
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql start
sudo service mysql stop
```

Comment: I thought stopping a service was temporarly, and it did not change anything about the software that starts at system start?

Comment: @Cheiron Yes, that is correct

Comment: "mysql stop/waiting" - does this means I have stopped mysql server? If so then can you tell why I can not start MySQL came with XAMPP-LINUX server ? I think there is a port conflict between two instances of mysql server. Do you know how to fix that ?